# How do I catch the top 50 strokes of TEXT? ( Google Sheet)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want Google Sheet to catch "https://finance.yahoo.com/".

[image: Picture]

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/
//div/div/div[2]/h3
=IMPORTXML(A2,A3)
```

But he can only catch the first ten, How do I catch the top 50 strokes of TEXT?

Answer (score 0):

Only the first ten news are included in the original html.

The others are loaded by JavaScript depending on the page scroll height, so you could not get them with `IMPORTXML`

Comment: I have seen find out XHR link can get, 
But after I tried to find LINK, I still couldn't get the following information.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You may then need to use Google Apps Script or create custom formula to output the json